# Twitter gem geocode not working, can't restrict tweet to certain lat and long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

Following the [Twitter Gem Doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Search), everytime I search I should be able to set the `geocode` to certain latitude and longtitude.

I'm gonna set my lat and long at Mountain View, which is (37.3894, 122.0819), and search within 10,000 miles within that location.

```
<% $client.search(@tweet.topic, result_type: "popular", geocode: "37.3849, 122.0819, 10000mi").take(5).each do |tweet|%>
    #print tweet
<% end %>
```

Is there anything wrong with my code above? If I remove the `geocode` parameter, it will actually return 5 tweets on the selected topic, but if I add the geocode in, it just doesn't return anything.

I understand that it may be because no one has tweeted about that topic, but if it's within 10,000 miles, I really don't think that is a possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, but longitude for Mountain View is wrong, should be  `-122.0819` since it's West and [West is negative and East is positive](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/geo/search) . Also, after reading https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets I think that setting radius to 10,000 miles might not work because:

> A maximum of 1,000 distinct “sub-regions” will be considered when using the radius modifier.

I'm not sure what 'sub-regions' are exactly, but there is a limit :) and bigger number will most likely just be ignored.

BTW, because of the wrong longitude you were  searching for tweets in China, where Twitter is blocked.